# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error when making a HTTP request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oauth-2.0, box-api

Hi I'm in the process of authenticating a user via OAuth 2.0 and I'm getting a Access-Control-Allow-Origin error (`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`) when making the following POST request:

```
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST',path,true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onload = function() {
    var text = xhr.responseText;
    alert('Response from request to ' + path + ': ' + text);
};
xhr.onerror = function() {
    alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
};
xhr.send(params);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I've looked into CORS, JSONP, and adding callback=? to the url but nothing I've tried is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developers.box.com/docs/

> The Box API supports CORS on an
>   app-by-app basis. If you’re building an application that needs CORS,
>   please contact us with a description of your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to do this is to use [YQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20632945/3110982) as it is described by their devs in the FAQ.