# POST request with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, box-api

llo i am using box api to for integration they have given just curl to get access token which is as follow

```
is curl https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token \
-d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code={your_code}&client_id={your_client_id}&client_secret={your_client_secret}' \
-X POST
```

I want to get access token using jquery ajax request i have tired my code like this as follow :

```
var data2= '{"grant_type":"authorization_code", "client_id":"61oliuyi1jckqos0j8zzl9h4t791umux" ,"client_secret":"Oi1XS56al61oOrrvAL3i5gdPTfe7QO9V" ,"code" :"'+code+'"}';
var data1 = JSON.parse(data2);

$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url:  "https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token",
                    data: data1,
                    success: function(json) {
                        console.log(e);
                       alert("success"+json);
                    },
                    error: function(e) {
                        console.log(e)
                        alert("Failure"+ JSON.stringify(e));

                    }
                });

MLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: Also please post what your issue is,to where have you narrowed it.

Comment: MLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simply due to cross-domain request. The **Javascript Origin Policy is going to prevent you from making Ajax request to the API from another domain** (like localhost, which you are using). Nice explanation of the error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636765).

As you are trying to use Box.com API, you should use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) to make your code working. [This](http://developers.blog.box.com/2011/09/28/using-the-box-api-with-javascript/) dev article from their blog shows exactly how to integrate YQL, and seems to be the best option.

Comment: what is the solution then

Comment: Use YQL -> http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/. The code is described in the article i linked above.

Comment: Alternatively, use some server side logic to interact with the service (there are some libs for ruby on rails and probably others)

Comment: Generally, it's better to summarize some of the information from external links, providing as much information to get to the point that the problem can be solved, in case the page disappears in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url:  "https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token",
                    data: data1,
                    dataType:"json",
                    success: function(val) {
                        console.log(e);
                       alert("success"+val);
                    },
                    error: function(e) {
                        console.log(e)
                        alert("Failure"+ JSON.stringify(e));

                    }
                });
```

Comment: This will still fail due to the common origin policy enforced by web browsers