# How to get file content from box.com service using ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, box-api

I'm trying to get the content of CSS file from box.com using direct link and attach it to the head tag, but it doesn't work.

```
$.ajax({                
        url: "https://app.box.com/shared/static/" + file_hash + ".css",                
        data: { client_id : '6guib1cgnk8uk2kdre45rjg7lt2xayegl94' },
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
          $("<style></style>").appendTo("head").html(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
);
```

Cuold anyone explain how to make it work?

**It returns an error Object:**

```
Object
abort: function ( statusText ) {
always: function () {
complete: function () {
done: function () {
error: function () {
fail: function () {
getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {
overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
progress: function () {
promise: function ( obj ) {
readyState: 0
responseText: undefined
setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
state: function () {
status: 0
statusCode: function ( map ) {
statusText: "error"
success: function () {
then: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ )
```

Comment: what is the error? what do you see on the console or network tab? Is it a JS error or a network/request error? Can you give an example value for `file_hash`?

Comment: Here is an example for file_hash: https://app.box.com/shared/static/2mbz6a9olevi86oi43kk.css

Comment: No errors in network tab

Comment: I'll have to check this at home, since I don't have access to `app.box.com` where I work.

Comment: can you add an image of the network tab for this particular request?

Comment: https://app.box.com/s/jckd4mfgb9ehir8akvm4

Comment: https://app.box.com/s/6stz2y92nhivbs4fvvfj

Comment: again, I don't have access to app.box so I'll check this at home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the error I receive when I execute your code:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://app.box.com/shared/static/2mbz6a9olevi86oi43kk.css. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

The problem is that you're making a cross-domain (CORS) request, but [JavaScript is limited to requesting resources on the same domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433655/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-or) unless the target application specifically allows it.

Box does not allow CORS requests by default, but [they will enable them on per-application basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333612/access-control-allow-origin-error-when-making-a-http-request). You'll need to contact Box support with a description of your use case.